# How to avoid scheduling conflicts for a timetable problem

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, integer-programming, opl

I'm trying to create a schedule for shifts for each employee given employee shift availability. I have a tuple defined to include shift start time, shift end time, max people on shift. The input also includes a list of arrays for employee shift preferences, For example [[1 0 0 1 1],...] which represents that employee 1 is available for shifts 1, 4, 5 but not 2, 3. Note that shift times are not mutually exclusive and can overlap.

I have a decision variable x[i,j] which is 1 if employee i is staffed for shift j, 0 otherwise. After I execute, I'm expecting x[i,j] to be a matrix indicating for each employee which shift they are assigned to. I have my other constraints including shift capacity. But I'm stuck on how to create the constraint to make sure that assigned shifts are not overlapping.

One idea I have is to do compare x[i,j] and x[i,k] where j =/= k and see if they checking if start time of i > end time of j OR start time of j > end time of i. But I'm not sure how to implement this in OPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the start and end time of each shift `j` are known constants. Let me call them `start[j]` and `end[j]`. So you should be able to use these to specify, using the `forall` construct, the pairs `(j,k)` such that the shifts `j` and `k` don't overlap.

You will find examples of using `forall`  in the examples installed with the product in the sub-directories of `[InstallDir]/opl/examples/opl`. More specifically, models that include constructs that you can look at are `models/Staffing/staffing.mod`, `timetabling/timetabling.mod`, and `teambuilding/teambuilding.mod`.